# Issues reading with pandas.read_table

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read in and manipulate some text files I have as outputs with statistics from an MRI analysis I ran.

With a for loop I would like to index into each subjects folder and convert their txt file with summary statistics into a data_frame, drop some of the rows that are not necessary, and concatenate each subject's now cleaned data_frame with a master data_frame. I seem to be reading in the txt file and getting it into the data_frame. However I am running into two issues I can't troubleshoot when trying to drop rows.

The txt file is organized like so.....

```
# Title Pathway Statistics
#
# generating_program


/cell_root/software/freesurfer/6.0.0/sys/bin/dmri_pathstats



# cvs_version


Count 2000
Volume 98
Len_Min 67
Len_Max 92
Len_Avg 81.219
Len_Center 87
AD_Avg 0.00152315
AD_Avg_Weight 0.00151198
AD_Avg_Center 0.00141413
```

*Although there is one row with many spaces that might be related to the issue in terms of reading the data in?*

```
# cmdline



/cell_root/software/freesurfer/6.0.0/sys/bin/dmri_pathstats --intrc 

/homes/dcallow/dti_freesurf/trac/Ex.AES115.long.base_AES115/dpath/fmajor_PP_avg33_mni_bbr --dtbase 

/homes/dcallow/dti_freesurf/trac/Ex.AES115.long.base_AES115/dmri/dtifit --path fmajor --subj Ex.AES115.long.base_AES115 --out 

/homes/dcallow/dti_freesurf/trac/Ex.AES115.long.base_AES115/dpath/fmajor_PP_avg33_mni_bbr/pathstats.overall.txt --outvox 

/homes/dcallow/dti_freesurf/trac/Ex.AES115.long.base_AES115/dpath/fmajor_PP_avg33_mni_bbr/pathstats.byvoxel.txt
```

I tried removing the drop line however I then get a different error that occurs earlier in the code which is also odd?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./txt_2_excel.sh", line 18, in 
>   df=pd.read_table('pathstats.overall.txt', delim_whitespace=True,names=['measure','value','excess1','excess2','excess3','excess4'])
>         File "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 678, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>         File "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 440, in _read
>       parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>         File "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>
> line 787, in **init**
>       self._make_engine(self.engine)
>         File "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1014, in _make_engine
>       self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>         File "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1708, in **init**
>       self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>         File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
>         File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
>       FileNotFoundError: File b'pathstats.overall.txt' does not exist

```
#!/Users/amos/anaconda3/bin/python

# Pythono3 code to rename multiple
# files in a directory or folder

# importing os module
import os
import pandas as pd
#set working directory to where files are stored

os.chdir("/Volumes/DANIEL/trac_stats")

df_master = pd.DataFrame()
for tract in os.listdir("/Volumes/DANIEL/tract_names/"):
    for subj in os.listdir("/Volumes/DANIEL/trac/"):

os.chdir("/Volumes/DANIEL/trac/{0}/dpath/{1}/".format(subj,tract))
        os.getcwd()
        df=pd.read_table('pathstats.overall.txt', delim_whitespace=True,names=['measure','value','excess1','excess2','excess3','excess4'])
df=df.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,18,20,22,23,25,26,28,29,31,32])
    df['subj']=subj
    df_master=pd.concat([df_master,df])
    print(df_master)

os.chdir("/Volumes/DANIEL/trac_stats/")
df_master.to_excel('trac_stats')
```

This should produce an excel sheet with a `['measure','value','excess1','excess2','excess3','excess4']` column and rows `12,13,19,21,24,and 27` of data for each subject in a excel sheet named `trac_stats`.

I get the following error

> File "./txt_2_excel.sh", line 20, in  File
>   "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 3697, in drop errors=errors) File
>   "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 3111, in drop obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level,
>   errors=errors) File
>   "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 3143, in _drop_axis new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
>   File
>   "/Users/amos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 4404, in drop '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
>   KeyError: '[32] not found in axis'

Comment: because you have droped column 32, you are not able to read it again. Also you seem to have changed the directory where 'pathstats.overall.txt' cannot be found.